# Schedule Sync in SyncToy 2.1 Windows 10

Tags: windows, synchronization, windows-10

I have been attempting to use SyncToy 2.1 in order to sync my files between my personal and work drives. When I try to put this on a weekly schedule, it's not working through task scheduler in Windows 10, when it worked perfectly in Windows 7.

I use the parameter -R and ensured that all of the paths in the 'action' of the scheduled task are correct

```
C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe
```

According to SyncToy, the full command to sync all of the pairs is:

```
"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R
```

Answer (score 0):

SyncToy 2.1 does NOT work with Windows 10 for some reason. However, we can still use SyncToy and tie it to a scheduled task with Task Scheduler by using this workaround.

Create a batch file (.bat) and put in the following text:

```
"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R
```

Save the batch file in any folder you like on your local drive (i.e. sync.bat). Then create a task through Task Scheduler that will run this batch file, instead of using Task Scheduler to directly open SyncToy and run the folder pairs.